# Differences in floating point between JDK 8 and JDK 13

Tags: java, floating-point

It seems that JDK 8 and JDK 13 have different floating points.
I get on JDK 8, using Math:

```
cos(2.3) = -0.666276021279824
```

And on JDK 13:

```
cos(2.3) = -0.6662760212798241
```

How does this happen? Difference shows on 11th Gen Intel and on AMD Ryzen using Windows 10.

**Edit 20.03.2022:**
Using Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits()) I get different bit patterns:
I get on JDK 8:

```
cos(2.3) = 0xbfe5522217302fe0
```

And I get on JDK 13:

```
cos(2.3) = 0xbfe5522217302fe1
```

Comment: How are you displaying the numbers?

Comment: I am using Double.toString() to display the result.

Comment: Add details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: What happens if you use `StrictMath`?

Comment: With StrictMath, the JDK 13 result matches the JDK 8 result. Oki Doki.

Comment: For what it's worth, using libraries wih arbitrary precision, we can show that exact cos of nearest double to 2.3 extends like this ...302fe09b9492... Thus the exact value is in between the two, nearer to the JDK 13 output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a JVM intrinsic function for `Math.cos`, which is described in the related issue [JDK-8242461](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242461). The behavior experienced there is not considered an issue:

> The returned results reported in this bug are indeed adjacent floating-point values [*this is the case here as well*]
>
> [...]
>
> Therefore, while it is possible one or the other of the returned values is outside of the accuracy bounds, just have different return values for Math.cos is not in and of itself evidence of a problem.
>
> For reproducible results, use the StrictMath.cos instead.

And indeed, disabling the intrinsics using `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:DisableIntrinsic=_dcos` (as proposed in the linked issue), causes `Math.cos` to have the same (expected) result as `StrictMath.cos`.

So it appears the behavior you are seeing here is most likely compliant with the `Math` documentation as well.

Comment: Additionally: My (unprofessional) guess whould be that the difference between Java 8 and 13 could come from [JDK-8143353](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143353) which changed the `sin` and `cos` intrinsics.